# What happens when a cavitation bubble collapses

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics

I know that when a cavitation bubble collapses, heat is given off and a shockwave is formed.

What else happens? Is there increased water pressure in that region? Can the intensity of this implosion be measured using a hydrophone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a cavitation bubble collapses, its internal volume is headed towards zero and it drags the surrounding fluid with it, accelerating it radially inwards towards the eventual collapse point.

At the instant when the volume goes to zero, there persists a radially-inward velocity field of fluid elements which were set in motion previously and which contain kinetic energy, and at the same instant they are all pointing inwards to the same point where there is nowhere to go!

At that collapse point, forces rise to extremely high levels over extremely small areas, generating gigantic pressures in very short times. it is possible for the water right in the collapse point to get heated enough that it emits a burst of light with a blackbody spectrum indicating a peak temperature of thousands of degrees (this is called *sonoluminescence*).

If there is a rigid wall near the bubble as it collapses, the collapse will be drawn towards the wall and the radial flow field will exert gigantic pressure upon a vanishingly small point on the wall, which readily punches a microscopic dent into the wall. Successive dents from successive cavitation collapses can drill a pinhole right through the wall by this mechanism.

Even if the collapse is insufficient to physically dent the wall, it is usually sufficient to disrupt any oxide layer adsorbed onto the wall, exposing fresh unoxidized wall material beneath- which then immediately oxidizes. successive disruptions of the oxide layer then drill a pinhole or a cavity into the wall, a mechanism known as *cavitation corrosion*.

A piezoelectric chip near the collapsing bubble can pick up the acoustic signal, which can be processed into information about the pressure and duration of the collapse impact.

In inkjet printheads based on superheat boiling of the ink, this collapse happens right after each droplet of ink is ejected from its nozzles. You can hear the impacts by pressing a phonograph cartridge needle against the orifice plate of an operating inkjet printhead and plugging the cartridge into a guitar amplifier, so everyone in the lab can hear the printhead "sing".

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been trying to figure out how to measure the intensity of  the cavitation, I think the use of the chip or a hydrophone would be a good choice.